# Highcharts heatmap shows unkown grid on top

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I was wondering why I get this grid at the top of the heatmap (not all the time) :

http://jsfiddle.net/08hruku5/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {});
```

Comment: Please place the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `turboThreshold` to 0 resolves the problem.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/d0qfw4dc/